# Solving 2D parabolic PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Please forgive if this is simple, but I was wondering if one may be able to derive a closed-form solution to

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} & = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}, \\
u(0,x,y) & = \sin(x)\sin(y) \\
u(t,x,y) & = 0, \qquad (x,y) \in \partial \Omega
\end{align}

on $\Omega = [0,\pi] \times [0,\pi]$.  I'm aware of series solutions for when there is no mixed derivative term using separation of variables, but is there a method of deriving solutions for these sorts of PDEs?  I would appreciate a good push in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

You can make your PDE into the standard heat equation 
$u_t = u_{XX} + u_{YY}$
by introducing a linear change of variables $x = \sqrt{5/8} X + \sqrt{3/8} Y$, $y = \sqrt{5/8} X - \sqrt{3/8} Y$.  Unfortunately, this messes up the boundary conditions: the square $[0,\pi] \times [0,\pi]$ becomes a parallelogram, and so the eigenfunctions won't have a nice product structure.  Computing the eigenfunctions and eigenvalues of the Laplacian on a parallelogram seems to be not an easy problem: see e.g. [this discussion on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/143419/spectrum-of-dirichlet-laplacian-on-a-parallelogram).  There may not be a closed-form solution.